# virtuemart file upload no option

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

i installed **virtumart** 2.0.2 version on **Joomla 2.5** version. when i goes to upload a file to product **it only support for image files**, other type of files are not allowed. can anyone help me for solve this problem

Comment: Sounds like that's the way it was meant to be. You'll probably have to  extend the code yourself if you want it to do something different. Beware of allowing file uploads that aren't images because they can be a security risk.

Comment: I've worked with older versions of VM, and can say that there was additional backend logic for particular file types, so my guess is that just opening up "any old file" type wouldn't work anyways.  Could be wrong on the newer version, but the VM forums would likely have a better answer.

Comment: thanks and i'am going to edit the extension ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First up upgrade to the latest version ([2.0.6](http://virtuemart.net/news/list-all-news/418-virtuemart-206-bug-fix-release-new-languages-more-security)) there are serious security issues with VM prior to 2.0.6 (even [2.0.4 had serious security fixes](http://virtuemart.net/news/list-all-news/417-happy-easter-new-virtuemart-204-released-security-update-sqli) and would be would be better)
2. The product image interface is built only for images, if you are looking to upload other  files to use as virtual products then you will need to upgrade and add a VM extension.
3. I think it was 2.0.4 that added better support for electronic goods but to be able to [sell & ship virtual goods you will need this extension](http://extensions.virtuemart.net/extensions-virtuemart-2/shipment-for-virtual-products-detail) (from the core developers of VM)

Comment: thank for help..this extension is too cost for me.. :).. so i'm going to edit the vm extension